# Definition of Principal Fibrations

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fibration

$\require{AMScd}$
On page $412$, Hatcher defines a fibration $F\xrightarrow{}E\xrightarrow{}B$ is called principal if there is a commutative diagram

\begin{CD}
F@>{}>>E@>{}>>B\\
@VVV @VVV @VVV\\
\Omega B'@>{}>>F'@>{}>>E'@>{}>>B'
\end{CD}
where the second row is a fibration sequence and the vertical maps are weak homotopy equivalences. I assume Hatcher adopted this definition as it better served the discussion of Postinkov Towers. However, I have also seen an alternative definition of "Principal" fibration, which seemed more prevalant: a fibration $F\xrightarrow{} E \xrightarrow{} B$ is principal if it is the pullback fibration induced by the path-loop fibration of a "classifying space" $A$, and a "classifying map" $k:B\xrightarrow{ } A$.

It is not clear to me why the two definition are indeed equivalent? Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The second definition clearly implies Hatcher's. As written, Hatcher's definition is more general. Depending on how strictly the phrase 'is the pullback' is interpreted, the definitions could be identical.